# how to get the size of a file from firebase storage with python and pyrebase

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-storage, pyrebase

I try to get the size of a file from the `storage` of python for which ready the elements with the following code:

```
storage = firebase.storage()
#storage.child("chat11.exe").put("PdaNetA5105.exe")
files = storage.list_files()
for file in files:
    print(file.name)
    print(storage.child(file.name).get_url(None))
    url = storage.child(file.name).get_url(None)
    if file.name == "chat1.PNG":
        sour = open(bytes(url))
```

but some idea does not work, what I try to do is show the process of uploading and downloading files from firebase.
Any ideas